<Shadow Include is replaced to which method in .NET 4.8
  <ItemGroup>
    <Shadow Include="Test References\accessor name" />
  </ItemGroup>

This is the piece of code in my cs.proj for .NET3.5 project and now i'm in the need of migrating the whole project to .NET 4.8 framework . While building the unit tests "ResolveTestReferences" step was not getting performed. Due to this the dependencies in the accessor file is not resolved leading to the error. Can someone explain me how to resolve this issue. Is there any alternative for < Shadow include to include the accessor files in .NET 4.8
............................
